# Not sure what to do with this Close vote

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, old-questions, popularity

This question just popped up on the close vote feed:

[How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory)

It's 5 years old and about file systems.

In my opinion it should be closed, it's not programming related, however it's got over 250 up votes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think it is not programming related? Unless you are generating files programmatically I guess  you are unlikely to hit these limits.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just because a question is highly upvoted doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed. What is and isn't on-topic on Stack Overflow has changed over the years and as more sites have been added into the Stack Exchange network, which can make older, upvoted questions off-topic or otherwise close-worthy. If you feel it should be closed, vote to close it.

In this particular instance I agree with you - the question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: 5 years old question is [too old to migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/165773 "feature implemented since Oct 18 '12")

Comment: @gnat Fair enough, thank you for bringing that to my attention - I'll remove the reference to it.

Comment: I completely disagree. This question looks absolutely programming related, and on topic. It talks about files being uploaded to a web site, names being stored in a database, etc. It seems obvious that this is about files that are created and managed programmatically, and the question is how to do that properly without running into trouble because of system limitations.

Comment: @RetoKoradi If you feel that it was incorrectly closed then it is within your power to cast a vote to reopen the question. However I disagree with your assessment. The focus of the question is not a programming question, it is tangentially related at best and as such it *is* off-topic.